# How can resolution be applied to prove this statement is satisfiable

Tags: proof-explanation, predicate-logic

Use resolution to show that the compound proposition (p ∨ q) ∧ (¬p ∨ q) ∧ (p ∨ ¬q) ∧ (¬p ∨¬q) is not satisfiable?
I have solved this by taking the first two and the last two using resolution and got F
However can't I take the first and last one (p ∨ q)∧ (¬p ∨¬q) and get (q v -q) = T
and the middle two and also get T
making the statement true?

Comment: Maybe the brave anonymous person who has proposed to close this question doesn't know what "resolution" is ; I see only this reason which has made him/her give this advice. Otherwise, on which ground this question which is well formulated and displays work on it should be closed !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is asked to use resolution, here is a very simple proof:

$$\begin{matrix}
\text{(p ∨ q)} & & \text{(¬p ∨ q)} & & \text{(p ∨ ¬q)} & & \text{(¬p ∨¬q)}\\
\searrow &&\swarrow && \searrow && \swarrow\\
&\text{q}&&&&\text{¬q}&\\
&&\searrow &&\swarrow && \\
&&&\square&&&
\end{matrix}$$

where two successive arrows like this $\searrow \ \swarrow$ mean "resolution" and $\square$ means "false".

Therefore you do not need to make a separate treatment with the first pair and then the second pair.